# Passing a parameter to another function

Tags: java, arraylist, parameter-passing

I wrote a code for hangman, and i want to pass the randomly guessed word(randomly guessed from a text file), to be passed to a function `hangman()` where i can get the length of the word. a random word will be guessed from the `getRandomWord(String path)` function and I have passed value obtained to `function()` But cannot seem to pass the and get the result.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Main ma = new Main();
        String stm= null;

        loadWords();
        //hangman(w);
        function();

    }

    public static String[] loadWords() {

        System.out.println("Loading words from file :");

        try {
            File myObj = new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Main\\words.txt");
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
            while (myReader.hasNext()) {
                String data = myReader.nextLine().toLowerCase();
                String[] spl = data.split(" ");
                System.out.println(spl.length + " words loaded");
                return spl;
            }
            myReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
        // TODO: Fill in your code here
    }

public static String getRandomWord(String path) throws IOException {
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] wordline = line.split("\\s+");
                for (String word : wordline) {
                    words.add(word);
                }
            }
        }
        Random rand = new Random();
        return words.get(rand.nextInt(words.size()));
    }

    public static List< String> getRemainingLetters(ArrayList< String> lettersGuessed) {
        String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        String[] alpha1 = alpha.split("");
        ArrayList< String> alpha2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(alpha1));
        for (int i = 0; i < lettersGuessed.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < alpha2.size(); j++) {
                if (alpha2.get(j).equals(lettersGuessed.get(i))) {
                    alpha2.remove(j);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return alpha2;
    }

    public static void function() throws IOException {

        int numGuesses = 5;
        String w = getRandomWord("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Main\\words.txt");

        String[] word = w.split("");
        ArrayList< String> wList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(word));
        ArrayList< String> wAnswer = new ArrayList< String>(wList.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < wList.size(); i++) {
            wAnswer.add("_ ");
        }
        int left = wList.size();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean notDone = true;
        ArrayList< String> lettersGuessed = new ArrayList< String>();

        while (notDone) {
            System.out.println();
            String sOut = "";

            List< String> lettersLeft = getRemainingLetters(lettersGuessed);
            for (String s : lettersLeft) {
                sOut += s + " ";
            }
            System.out.println("Letters Left: " + sOut);

            sOut = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < wList.size(); i++) {
                sOut += wAnswer.get(i);
            }
            System.out.println(sOut + " Guesses left:" + numGuesses);
            System.out.print("Enter a letter(* exit): ");
            String sIn = scanner.next();
            numGuesses--;
            if (sIn.equals("*")) {
                break;
            }
            lettersGuessed.add(sIn);
            for (int i = 0; i < wList.size(); i++) {
                if (sIn.equals(wList.get(i))) {
                    wAnswer.set(i, sIn);
                    left--;
                }
            }
            if (left == 0) {
                System.out.println("Congradulations you guessed it!");
                break;
            }
            if (numGuesses == 0) {

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (String string : wList) {
                    sb.append(string);

                }
                String stm = sb.toString();
                System.out.println("Sorry you ran out of guesses, the word was: " + stm);
                break;
            }

        }

    }

    public static void hangman(String word) {

        System.out.println("Welcome to Hangman Ultimate Edition");
        System.out.println("I am thinking of a word that is " + word.length() + " letters long");
        System.out.println("-------------");


    }
}
```

Comment: You have to call function to pass value or create a global variable

Comment: This would be a perfect use of a debugger.

Comment: @Eklavya Can you give a example ?

Comment: @chinthanadissanayake show us full code then we can. Are you calling `hangman` from anywhere ?

Comment: @Eklavya - I've updated the full code above. and i'm only calling `hangman()` from `public static void main (String args [])` and not from anywhere else. but the proper output is not coming so i commented the `hangman()` from  `public static void main (String args [])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problems in your code:

1. Not passing the random word to the methods, `hangman` and `function`.
2. Instead of re-using the random word obtained from the method, `getRandomWord` in `main`, you have called `getRandomWord` again in the method, `hangman` which will give you a different random word causing incosistency.

   Given below is the corrected program with a sample run:

   ```
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.FileReader;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.Arrays;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.Random;
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
           String word = getRandomWord("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Main\\words.txt");
           hangman(word);
           function(word);
       }

       public static String getRandomWord(String path) throws IOException {
           List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
           try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
               String line;
               while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                   String[] wordline = line.split("\\s+");
                   for (String word : wordline) {
                       words.add(word);
                   }
               }
           }
           Random rand = new Random();
           return words.get(rand.nextInt(words.size()));
       }

       public static List<String> getRemainingLetters(ArrayList<String> lettersGuessed) {
           String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
           String[] alpha1 = alpha.split("");
           ArrayList<String> alpha2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(alpha1));
           for (int i = 0; i < lettersGuessed.size(); i++) {
               for (int j = 0; j < alpha2.size(); j++) {
                   if (alpha2.get(j).equals(lettersGuessed.get(i))) {
                       alpha2.remove(j);
                       break;
                   }
               }
           }
           return alpha2;
       }

       public static void function(String w) throws IOException {
           // The available number of guesses = length of the random word
           int numGuesses = w.length();

           // Split the random word into letters
           String[] word = w.split("");

           ArrayList<String> wList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(word));
           ArrayList<String> wAnswer = new ArrayList<String>(wList.size());

           for (int i = 0; i < wList.size(); i++) {
               wAnswer.add("_ ");
           }

           int left = wList.size();
           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
           boolean notDone = true;
           ArrayList<String> lettersGuessed = new ArrayList<String>();

           while (notDone) {
               System.out.println();
               String sOut = "";

               List<String> lettersLeft = getRemainingLetters(lettersGuessed);
               for (String s : lettersLeft) {
                   sOut += s + " ";
               }
               System.out.println("Letters Left: " + sOut);

               sOut = "";
               for (int i = 0; i < wList.size(); i++) {
                   sOut += wAnswer.get(i);
               }
               System.out.println(sOut + " Guesses left:" + numGuesses);
               System.out.print("Enter a letter(* exit): ");
               String sIn = scanner.next();
               numGuesses--;
               if (sIn.equals("*")) {
                   break;
               }
               lettersGuessed.add(sIn);
               for (int i = 0; i < wList.size(); i++) {
                   if (sIn.equals(wList.get(i))) {
                       wAnswer.set(i, sIn);
                       left--;
                   }
               }
               if (left == 0) {
                   System.out.println("Congradulations you guessed it!");
                   break;
               }
               if (numGuesses == 0) {

                   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                   for (String string : wList) {
                       sb.append(string);

                   }
                   String stm = sb.toString();
                   System.out.println("Sorry you ran out of guesses, the word was: " + stm);
                   break;
               }
           }
       }

       public static void hangman(String word) {
           System.out.println("Welcome to Hangman Ultimate Edition");
           System.out.println("I am thinking of a word that is " + word.length() + " letters long");
           System.out.println("-------------");
       }
   }
   ```

   **A sample run:**

   ```
           Welcome to Hangman Ultimate Edition
   I am thinking of a word that is 3 letters long
   -------------

   Letters Left: a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 
   _ _ _  Guesses left:3
   Enter a letter(* exit): c

   Letters Left: a b d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 
   _ _ _  Guesses left:2
   Enter a letter(* exit): a

   Letters Left: b d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 
   _ _ _  Guesses left:1
   Enter a letter(* exit): t
   Sorry you ran out of guesses, the word was: fox
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To make your existing code run, you should just clean up the `main` method:

- remove unused code:

```
Main ma = new Main(); // no need to create an instance, you use only static methods
String stm= null;     // not used anywhere
loadWords();          // not used, entire method may be removed:
                      // it reads words only in the first line
```

- fix method `function` to have a `String w` parameter, move getting the random word out of this method.

Thus, resulting changes should be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String word = getRandomWord("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Main\\words.txt");
    hangman(word);
    function(word);
}

public static void function(String w) throws IOException {

    int numGuesses = 5;

    String[] word = w.split("");
// ... the rest of this method remains as is
}
```